# How can I Implement my command loop "for" correctly?

Tags: batch-file

I would like to know why my the loop `FOR /L` doesn't work. Here is the code I have tried:

```bat
set machine_0=item1
set machine_1=item2

FOR /l %%i IN (0,1,%%i) Do call :FOR_VALUE %%i

:FOR_VALUE

echo !machine_%%i!  
set chemin="%mode%\!machine_%%i!" 
if not exist %chemin% mkdir %chemin%
```

Any ideas?

Comment: the `%%i` token cannot be evaluated in the brackets part of the for loop. Try to set `2` instead.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a proper failure description! Describe exactly what your code is supposed to do and what it actually does! Consult the help articles [ask] and [mcve]!

Comment: Hint2: 1. before the `:FOR_VALUE` label place `goto :EOF`; 2. `%%i` cannot be evaluted in the scope of the sub-routine, but you could use arguments (see `call /?`)...

Comment: You certainly do not need to make a CALL to a function to do what you want to do.

Comment: You would also need to enable delayed expansion to make your code work.

Comment: @npocmaka It is not possible to have a variable instead to set "2" ?

Comment: @joemiler - yes you can have a variable there like `%total_count%` , you can use even the command line arguments like `%~1` but not the loop token.